# Matlab: How to delete prefix from strings

Tags: string, matlab, prefix

Problem: From TrajCompact, i find all the prefix and the value after prefix, using regexp, with this code:

```
[digits{1:2}] = ndgrid(0:4);
  for k=1:25
  matches(:,k)=regexp(TrajCompact(:,1),sprintf('%d%d.*',digits{1}(k),digits{2}(k)),'match','once');
  end
```

I want only the postfix of matches, how can delete the prefix from matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Method using regular expressions

You can put the `.*` section in a group by enclosing it in parenthesis (i.e. `(.*)`). Matlab has some peculiar 'token' nomenclature for this. In any case, an example of how it works:

```
[match, group] = regexp('25blah',sprintf('%d%d(.*)',2,5),'match','once','tokens');
```

Then:

1. match would be a char array containing '25blah'
2. group would be a 1x1 cell array containing the string 'blah'.

That is, the variable `group` would hold what you're looking for.

#### Hack method

Since your prefix is always two digits, you could also just take everything from the 3rd character of the match onwards:

```
my_string = match(3:end);
```

#### other comments

You may want to require the prefix to occur *at the beginning of the string* by adding `^` to the beginning of your regular expression. Eg., make the line:

```
[match, group] = regexp('25blah',sprintf('^%d%d(.*)',2,5),'match','once','tokens');
```

As it is, your current regular expression would match strings like `zzzzzzzzz25stuff`. I'm not sure if you want that (assuming it can occur in your data).

Comment: 'group' in my code is a cell array with many empty array: how can I trasform it in a matrix? I try   ''>> postfix(cellfun(@isempty,postfix)) = {''};
>> Y = reshape([postfix{:}],size(postfix)); but reshape gives error.